# How do you access tableView in Master-Detail storyboard template?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4

I'm using storyboarding and the Master-Detail Core Data template in Xcode4.

I want to set the background image for my tableView on the master view controller.

To do this was simple for the iPhone, I just did this in viewDidLoad of the MasterViewController.m:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

However, this doesn't work for the iPad; the default background is being shown instead in the master tableView.

I wouldn't think this was a splitViewController issue; from the perspective of the MasterViewController object, he should always have the same tableView, right? In fact, I know this is the case, because this code works on both iPad and iPhone, a line above the "backgroundColor" assignment, and this is using the same "self.tableView" object:

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"separator.png"]];
```

This is what it looks like on the iPhone, with both the separator and background image working (sorry, can't post pictures inline yet):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaULS.png

And, using the same code, on the iPad:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVKmt.png

What do I have to set in order to set the background image on the master tableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I found the secret sauce:

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage]];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:backgroundView];
```

The key is using `[self.tableView setBackgroundView:...]`instead of the property `self.tableView.backgroundColor = ...`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the background clear in interface builder. Then, you need to say `self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` in your `viewDidLoad`. Finally, put a UIView behind it with the appropriate background color. For some reason, the background stuff is overridden in the UITableView itself.

Comment: This did not seem to do the trick, but thanks for the input.

FYI, I think the color set in IB is irrelevant, as long as you're setting it in code (though I certainly could be wrong). I tried adding a subview in viewDidLoad, but no matter what I did (even with    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImageView];), the imageView showed up on top of the tableView. I did find a solution, though, and am about to post details.

Comment: Excellent. Glad you found the issue. Unfortunately, the color setting in IB still matters (something to do with the way the view is lazily inflated). At least it mattered on the Xcode version 4.1 of the SDK.